# Loading Images into Android Mobile AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, loading, photo

I want my app to open the photo gallery of the android mobile and copy that photo to my installation folder of my App. How do i do that in flash? What is the exact location of the photo gallery?

Comment: [Less than 10 seconds on google](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraRoll.html). Opens the Camera roll of the device, enables you to pick out a picture and returns it to you. I would say you don't need the location of the photo gallery, since you have the image, you can save it directly as a new file in your installation folder through the usual methods in the File class.

Comment: Can you like show me how?